# How Java Servlets Filters are Useful

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm reading about Java Filters, I understood it's implementation and how to use it, But I don't know why we use it. **As I read Filters used to filter the url to save/protected resources from illegal access, But I'm confused that We can do this same with session** then why Filters? After reading complete detail from [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial). I got this paragraph that is too close to clear my concept.

> In the last article, we learned how we can manage session in web
>   application and if we want to make sure that a resource is accessible
>   only when user session is valid, we can achieve this using servlet
>   session attributes. The approach is simple but if we have a lot of
>   servlets and jsps, then it will become hard to maintain because of
>   redundant code. If we want to change the attribute name in future, we
>   will have to change all the places where we have session
>   authentication.

Ok above paragraph clearing concept as theory base, but can anyone show me example of program that show Filters really useful for Java Servlets. How web-application or resources can affects with and without Filters?

Comment: The blog is erroneously written and you understood it in a different way.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you clear my confusion please? why we need/use servlets?

Comment: Short answer is to filter the requests and long answer will take latest an hour to explain ;) Always read offical docs

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you give me official link of Servlets? or any link that can clear my confusion. I'm really reading hard since 2 days to clear, why we use filters but still confused.. -_-

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ thanks, is there any offline html version for Servlets same as Java 8 docs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html Because I really don't know what need to learn in Java Servlets, because I don't have any good list.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a large webapp with 300 servlets, and 250 of them can only be accessed if you're authenticated. To prevent an unauthenticated user to access these 250 servlets, you would have, in each of those servlets, to repeat the following pseudo-code:

```java
if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    throw new ForbiddenException();
}
```

And when introducing the 251th servlet, you have a big chance of forgetting to add that check.

A filter allows saying the container: for all the requests going to `/private/*`, execute the following filter before calling the servlet mapped to the URL.

You can then forget about checking the authentication in the 250 servlets, and do it once and only once, in the filter.

Of course there are other use-cases: authorization checks, logging, performance measuring, etc.

Comment: @JBNizat, As I read Filters automatically invoked before servlets, But suppose I have 2 or more filters how they are connected to servlets? mean which filter invoked for which servlet?

Comment: Just like servlets are mapped to URLs, filters are also. You can also map a filter to a servlet, meaning that the filter is called whenever a request to that servlet is made.

Comment: better to have one filter than 250 servlets is nightmare.

Comment: I'll had that you can chain filters (i.e. have more than one).

Comment: I will add that the filter is called before and after the target Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Filters invoked before any servlet. This is the main difference. A good example of the filter is Struts2 filter.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.ng.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: Suppose I have servlet `A` and Filter `B` how I can map them that when Servlet `A` called then automatically Filter `B` should be invoke.

Comment: map them `/*` means everything

Comment: @RomanC but if I used any other map instead `/*` then? that filter will invoke for just that url?

Comment: Filter is invoked for url that matches the filter mapping pattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that is incorrect. Filters can be mapped to servlets. Quote from the spec: *Filters can be associated with a servlet using the <servlet-name> element*

Comment: @RomanC Ok just last to confirm, we just need to write everything in Filters even conditions and everything, ( there is nothing to edit/add in servlet to connect with filter? )

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks - that I didn't know. TIL.

Comment: @JBNizet As I was expecting, can you give me any example?

Comment: @UnKnown In the example about you use only one filter and nothing more is necessary.

Comment: @RomanC but suppose I don't want to invoke filter for `Xs` servlets then How I can do that? because you advise me to already map `/*` that will work for each url.

Comment: @UnKnown A lot of ways exist, beginning from changing the filter mapping and continuing with parsing url.

Comment: @RomanC any exact and useful link please?

Comment: @UnKnown http://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html - "... and handles all requests".

Answer (score -1):

One of the benefits of Filters is that you can apply a Filter to many Servlets instead of writing same code in each servlet you have.

**Edit** : to avoid confusion, you don't apply a filter directly for a servlet but for an URI.